# В чем разница возвращаемого значения available() и read(byte[] b)

Tags: java, файлы, filestream

```
input.available() // return 9
input.read(new byte[input.read()]) // return 8
```

Считывая с файла потоком `FileInputStream` input получаем данные значения. Разве метод `available` не должен возвращать количество доступных битов так же как и вторая конструкция?

файл содержит следующий текст:

> javatest1

Comment: `input.read(new byte[input.read])` - опечатка, и должно быть `input.read(new byte[input.read()])`?

Comment: Да, опечатка, благодарю

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `.available()` не блокирует поток выполнения при отсутствии данных , а `.read()` - блокирует.
- `.available()` возвращает **примерное** количество доступных для чтения байтов, а `.read(byte[] b)` - количество считанных в буфер (массив байтов), от `-1` при достижении конца потока данных и до размера массива (`b.length`).
- `.available()` лишь проверяет наличие данных, а `.read()` - их считывает.

[Документация по InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html).
То же самое справедливо и для [FileInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html).

---

Как работает `input.read(new byte[input.read()])`:

1. Происходит считывание одного байта из потока с помощью `input.read()`.
2. Его значение (в данном случае код символа `j` - `106`), которое возвращает  `.read()` (именно значение первого байта, а не количество байтов), используется для создания массива из 106 байтов.
3. В данный байтовый массив считываются данные из потока.
4. Данных в потоке оставалось 8 байтов (первый уже был считан в пункте 1), и в буфер они входят (`106 > 8`), так что `.read(byte[] b)` возвращает количество считанных байтов - 8.

Comment: Возможно я не верно понимаю, но в файле у меня 9 символов, соответственно ожидаемый результат - 9 байт. Метод .available() возвращает ожидаемый результат. Что именно я не учитываю в своих рассуждениях  @regent ?

Comment: И да, правильно ли я понимаю, что конструкция byte[] b = new byte[input.available()] - заведомо некорректна, для будущего использования метода .read()?

Comment: @mamba0767 да, заведомо некорректна в том плане что это не даст гарантий, что вы прочитаете за раз все доступные байты. По поводу вашего примера из вопроса - обновил ответ, добавив объяснение того, что там происходит.

Comment: а на Ваш взгляд данная конструкция оптимальна для простейшего побайтового чтения с файла?

Comment: @mamba0767 для простейшего байтового чтения из файла я бы использовал `int read = input.read(buffer);` внутри `while (read > 0)`. Это, по-моему, лучше, чем читать по одному байту. Можно и всякие обёртки над `InputStream` использовать для, например, более удобного, построчного чтения из текстового файла.

Answer (score 0):

Второй способ не может вернуть значение больше, чем размер массива.

P.s. для получения длины файла используйте

```
new File("Ваш файл").length();
```

Comment: А в чем измеряется "длина" файла?

Comment: байтами, очевидно, читайте документацию: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length()